*Accurate* extraction of information from complex PDFs - Corporate income tax return forms
Looking for ideas on how to accurately extract data from complex pdf files, specifically, the prescribed forms/schedules that are included in Corporate Tax Returns.
Following are screenshots of a section referred to as Schedule L of a US Corporate Return (item 1), the resulting output and my code (item 2), and an excerpt of my code (item 3).
The results are quite poor - missed entire columns and didn't even recognize the lower half of the table for "Liabilities and Shareholders' Equity".
The IRS (and other revenue authorities) publish stylesheets that developers use in creating tax compliance software applications. See item #4 below. Can these be leveraged? AI/ML??

Screen capture - US Corporate Tax Return

Output

Code excerpt:


Packages used:
"pymupdf",  # For PDF parsing
"pdfplumber",  # For table extraction
"pytesseract",  # For OCR
"Pillow",  # For image manipulation
"pandas",  # For data processing
# Step 1: Extract text and images from the PDF
def extract_text_and_images(pdf_path):
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    text_blocks = []
    images = []
    for page_num, page in enumerate(doc):
        text_blocks.extend(page.get_text("blocks"))
        for img_index, img in enumerate(page.get_images(full=True)):
            xref = img[0]
            base_image = doc.extract_image(xref)
            image_bytes = base_image["image"]
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
            images.append((page_num, img_index, image))
    doc.close()
    return text_blocks, images

# Step 2: OCR for embedded or scanned images
def perform_ocr(images):
    ocr_results = []
    for page_num, img_index, image in images:
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang="eng")
        ocr_results.append({"page": page_num, "index": img_index, "text": text})
    return ocr_results

# Step 3: Extract tables using pdfplumber
def extract_tables(pdf_path):
    tables = []
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            page_tables = page.extract_tables()
            tables.extend(page_tables)
    return tables

# Step 4: Parse extracted data and clean
def parse_data(text_blocks, ocr_results, tables):
    extracted_text = " ".join([block[4] for block in text_blocks])
    for ocr_result in ocr_results:
        extracted_text += " " + ocr_result["text"]
    labels_and_values = re.findall(r'([A-Za-z\s]+)\s*([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?)', extracted_text)
    table_data = [pd.DataFrame(table) for table in tables]
    return labels_and_values, table_data

# Step 5: Save and validate results
def save_results(labels_and_values, table_data):
    labels_df = pd.DataFrame(labels_and_values, columns=["Label", "Value"])
    labels_df.to_csv("output/extracted_labels.csv", index=False)
    for idx, table in enumerate(table_data):
        table.to_csv(f"output/table_{idx}.csv", index=False)


** Excerpt of IRS xsl for Schedule L**

Screen capture of IRS 860875_IRS990ScheduleL.xsl

the ACCURATE export by IRS will for those top 4 lines be `/Kids [<<
/T (f6_2[0])
/V (76,921)


<<
/T (f6_4[0])
/V (90,053)
]
/T (Line1[0])
<<
/Kids [<<
/T (f6_7[0])
/V (2,028)
]
/T (Line2a[0])
<<
/Kids [<<
/T (f6_12[0])
/V (2,028)
]
/T (Line2b[0])
<<
/Kids [<<
/T (f6_14[0])
/V (55,000)
<<
/T (f6_16[0])
/V (67,000)
]
/T (Line3[0])
]
/T (SchLTable[0])
]
/T (Page6[0])` Thus the AI will read the KEY VALUE PAIRS and check the conformance in seconds before any rejects sent to a human as more intelligent



KJ, thankyou for the response.  The bolded and italicized item I believe is in reference to the types of corporations that are eligible to efile.  Not sure about the comment "internal FDF database entries".  The IRS has published XSL that software developers can use to develop the XML file that gets electronically submitted.  PDF attachments are for documents for which an XML schema has not been provided by the IRS. Also, the part of your response that starts with "the ACCURATE export by IRS ..." appears to be for a Individual income tax return, not a corporate return.

AFAIK that is the same CIT XML form & the word /Kids refers to XMP nested entries so the XML db (XFDF) is reflected in the PDF surface (clients FDF) where the entries are injected by any FDF toolkit. (it is as quick as a click) Such forms are designed to be used in Adobe licensed servers where JS usually does the import/export but there should be no need when e-filing as the corporate individual does that online (at stated cost of burden !!) so the export is done by IRS at high speed by read those /Kids entries and compare those key value pairs in high speed plain text or  slower xml format.

If they accept raw XML  submissions then there should be no need to import the XML into the PDF but then again we are talking about autocratic double / triple inputs.
